# Excel 2003 digital signature on VBA project

Tags: excel, vba, certificate, digital-signature

I have a macro project that will be sent to users that require High Macro security. If I use the self-signed certificate, I am able to sign my code, but it is not a trusted cert.

I requested and received an enterprise certificate from our security team, but when I try to sign the code, I receive an error that states

> 'There was a problem with the digital certificate. The VBA project
>   could not be signed. The signature will be discarded.'

The cert request was generated from IIS, since that is the only way anyone around knows how to generate the enterprise level certs. My guess is that since I don't own the private key associated with the cert, Excel is rejecting it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can update your own question by editing it. You can vote for questions (upvote or downvote) and if you get the answer that satisfies your needs and answers your question, you can mark it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

i've been dealing with the same problem for 4 days, I tried to do my own CA with openssl and the makecert.exe tool, but nothing worked, util i realize that i didnt installed my certificate with the private key!!!..

talk with the ISS team and ask them to give you the private key generated for your certificate...

or you can try to make one:
http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/38/using-makecert-to-create-certificates-for-development
(quick tip.. include -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3 while you are creating your certificate)
remember to do the last part "pvk2pfx".

best regards

Answer (score 0):

First of all, yes, you need a private key of the certificate in order to sign anything.

Then, the certificate must include certain flags in Key usage and Extended Key Usage extensions.

And the last (but probably the most important) is that the certificate or its CA certificate should be trusted by the application that verifies the signature.

To make the story shorter, purchasing a certificate from one of known CAs (eg. [GlobalSign](http://www.globalsign.com/code-signing/)) is the best option.